# Delta option of term field missing in views

Tags: views, database, entities

So I have a view that's been working for the last year. now suddenly there is a missing broken handler.

Turns out that the missing field is a delta (field) of a term reference field, the term field is still available. Now even when creating a new view i can't add term reference delta

What could possibly be causing this. if someone could just give me a place to start that would be great.

this is the missing field from views export on the staging site.. which still works.. :/

```
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['delta']['id'] = 'delta';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['delta']['table'] = 'field_data_field_people_reference';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['delta']['field'] = 'delta';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['delta']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_people_reference_field_collection_item';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['delta']['value']['value'] = '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you accidentally change the amount of values this field takes to one then obviously there will be no delta... side note **I am an Idiot**